# Python: Update GUI After Instruction

Tags: python, pyside, sleep

I designed a program to solve Rubik's cubes, and now I'm building a GUI for it using PySide. My program generates a list of moves required to solve the cube, and then executes them one by one. I would like my program to show the status of the cube for a short period of time between each move.

Currently, I'm trying to use the time module to make the program wait between executing moves. Basically like this:

```
for move in algorithm:
    executeMove()
    updateDisplay()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I figured this method would work just fine. However, when I run the application, it looks like it's sleeping for the sum time of each of the sleep calls, then showing the end result of the algorithm. I would ideally like to make it show a move, sleep 0.1, show a move, sleep 0.1, etc.

Is the sleep function ideal for the type of behavior I'm trying to get? Should I be using something different entirely? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You'll probably want to use timers to get Qt to call a function of yours after 0.1s, then return, which gives Qt back control of the drawing and events and things.

Comment: Okay, so i tried to use a QTimer instead of the sleep function. Basically just replaced time.sleep(0.1) with QTimer.singleShot(100, updateDisplay). The program is still behaving the way it did originally.

Comment: Because you're still blocking the main Qt loop, and Qt will never update until you break out of that while loop and let it. A QTimer approach is possible, but will be quite different that what you have.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good to see a little more code, but it looks like you're probably blocking the main Qt thread. To accomplish what you want to do, you will need to be multi-threaded and use `pyQtSignal`s to update the UI. Here's a (maybe buggy) template

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    updateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, algorithm):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.algorithm = algorithm
        self.updateSignal.connect(self.updateDisplay)
        self.loopThread = None
        self.startMonitoring()
    def startMonitoring(self):
        self.loopThread = MonitorLoop(self.updateSignal.emit, self.algorithm)
        self.loopThread.start()
    def updateDisplay(self):
        """ Update the UI here"""
        pass


class MonitorLoop(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, signal, algorithm):
        super(MonitorLoop, self).__init__()
        self.signal = signal # needs to be a pyQtSignal if it will update the UI
        self.algorithm = algorithm
    def run(self):
        for move in self.algorithm:
            executeMove()
            self.signal()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

If you are using Qt 4, you will need to substitute `QtGui` for `QWidgets`. Of course, I don't actually know what `algorithm` is, so your implementation will need to accomodate that.